# What strings are actually being compared in the strcpy call of this assembler code?

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly

This is part of the assembler code

```
mov dword [esp+0x4], 0x80bf7a8
mov eax, dword [ebp-0x78] ; pointer to char array on heap
mov dword [esp], eax
call fcn.080482a0

...

0x080482a0   jmp dword [0x80ec03c]

...

0x080ec03c   .dword 0x0805c260 ; sym.strcmp
```

So basically, this means `strcmp(heap_ptr, 0x80bf7a8)` is called, and I think I just need to look up what is at `0x80bf7a8`. But I only find the following at that address:

```
0x080bf7a8   3000   xor byte [eax], al
```

I don't understand what's going on here. There are some strings right after that memory address, but they're strings that get printed by the program and it wouldn't make sense for them to be  used in this strcmp (also they're at the wrong memory address anyway). But how can what looks to be an xor instruction be passed on as an argument to strcmp?

Or is that just a misinterpretation of my reverse engineering tool (radare2) and it's actually comparing  the string on the heap to the word 3000, which is the null terminated ascii character for '0'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it is `'0'` character. Radare just thought it is a code for some reason and disassmebled `30 00` into `xor byte [eax], al`.

It happens for IDA too, just mark this memory as data.